# What is 佈施? I found it on a bilingual blog

Tags: meaning

I have already looked this word up in mdbg, and have found nothing.

Comment: 布施 see iciba 

[佛教] alms giving ； donation

Comment: Or put the phrase on Google to find pages on the Gates Foundation, or the Sheng-Yen Lu Foundaiton or others  There it means grant giving.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you might want to tag it as religion (or move it to religion section in SE) as this is a question more related to buddhism than chinese language.  From this [link](http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%85%AD%E5%BA%A6):

布施

指把自身所擁有或所知道的施予他人。除了財物的布施 (財布施) 外，還包括佛法的傳揚 (法布施) 和信心的給予 (無畏布施)。

I'll try giving a simple explanation:

It means to give / donate all you have / all you knows (your knowledges) to others.  Other than giving out all your wealth, it includes spreading of buddhism and giving others confident.

Comment: He didn't know it was related to religion. He didn't know its meaning **at all**.

Comment: @ EnricoBrasil I figured, that's why I did not vote to anything, but a suggestion in the answer.